# What is one way to prove that there exists no ellipse that matches the exact curvature of the sin wave?

Tags: trigonometry, conic-sections

Preferably by not graphing both and showing they don't match visually. By the sin wave, I mean just plain old y=sinx.

Comment: Any ellipse including the degenerate one doesn't have any inflection point. i.e. the curvature never change sign. However, the sin wave $y = \sin x$ has an inflection point at $x = 0$. You cannot approximate the part of sin wave near $x = 0$ by any ellipse.

Comment: What do you mean with "match exact curvature" here? Conincide over an interval?

Comment: If curvature is properly defined, why not try using the definition? Or is calculus not allowed here?

Comment: What I mean by the definition of curvature is examining the osculating circles of the ellipse and the sine function. You'll probably see that there exists no choice of focii such that the osculating circles matches, ie the curvature is never the same. But that requires taking some limits, which may not be allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Both the sine wave and (a part of) an ellipse are given by analytic functions. Hence they are either identical or do not coincide over any open interval.

Answer (score 2):

An ellipse has all possible slopes, from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  The slope of a sine wave is limited from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: That doesn't rule out the sine wave being less than half of an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: An ellipse is formed by collecting all of the points where the distances from two foci add to a constant value.

While it is possible to approximate the sine curve using an ellise, the sine curve will soon spread apart from the ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

For an ellipse passing through a particular point, the first 4 (I think that's right) derivatives at that point will uniquely determine the ellipse. By comparing the the first 5 derivatives of sin at a particular point you could show sin diverges from the 'local ellipse' in the 5th derivative.

Answer (score 0):

By **reduction to the absurd**: Assume that the opposite were true. But first, let us shift the graphic of the sine function by $\dfrac\pi2$ to the right, so that its shape around $x=0$ might resemble that of a half ellipse centered in the origin. Now, on one hand, the shifted sine function is nothing else than $\cos x$ since $\sin\bigg(x+\dfrac\pi2\bigg)=\cos x$. On the other hand, an ellipse centered in the origin has the property that $\bigg(\dfrac xa\bigg)^2+\bigg(\dfrac yb\bigg)^2=1$. Here, $y=\cos x$. Making $x=0$, we deduce that $b=1$, since $\cos0$ is $1$. Then, by subtracting $\cos^2x$ from both sides, and extracting the radical, we have $\sin x=\dfrac xa$ for *x* around $0$, implying that the sine function is linear around the origin$(!)$. But $\sin x=2\sin\dfrac x2\cos\dfrac x2$ for **all** *x*, implying $\dfrac xa=2\dfrac x{2a}\sqrt{1-\bigg(\dfrac x{2a}\bigg)^2}$ for **all** *x* in the vicinity of $0$, which is absurd. QED.

Comment: But the sine IS linear around the origin. And I'd say your last sentence requires qualification aswell. Doesn't the limit of the right hand side equal the left hand side?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: Let us not confuse approximations with exact identities. Otherwise, as far as approximations are concerned, the portion of the sine and cosine function may very well be approximated by that of an arc of ellipse: but they may never overlap identically over any contiguous interval.

Comment: Can I ask what you formally mean by "in the vicinity of 0" in that case? I mean, in an epsilon delta manner of speaking, sine IS linear in the vicinity of 0, or so I thought :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: An open interval containing $0$. Obviously, $\sin x=x$ is only true for $0$ itself, and not for any other number. That $\sin x\approx x$ for $x\to0$ is indeed true, but the OP asked for an *exact match* between the graphics of the two functions.

Comment: OP asked for matching curvature! And curvature is well defined at single points, for example at x=0. Please correct me if I am mistaken though as I'm no expert, but I think we actually ARE interested in the limiting case here: "is there a point in which the osculating circles of the curves match exactly".

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist: Judging by both the OP's text, where he mentions “graphing both and showing they don't match visually”, as well as Haagen von Eitzen's answer, when he says that “[they] do not coincide over any open interval”, I assume curvature here simply refers to a segment of the function's curve.

Comment: With that interpretation, you could just express both curves as a function of y, take the difference and see if that equals 0 for any choice of a,b > 0. But this is probably getting too long winded for the comment section.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment, if you're looking for an open interval where the curves are identical, you can just express both as functions $f(x),g(x)$, examine $f(x)-g(x)$, and see if there exists a choice of $a,b>0$ that produces $f-g=0$. But that's not how we define curvature, atleast not in the class I took.

Curvature is a well defined property of a curve passing through a point: $\kappa = 1/R$ where R is the radius of the circle that best approximates the curve at a point. What your question boils down to is whether or not there is a point where this best approximating ("osculating") circle is the same for an ellipse and a sine.

Just thought I'd point that out, since most answers thus far has implied that curvature is a property of an INTERVAL and not a point, which is a hugely important distinction. Read more about osculating circles at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature, they're very interesting objects.